# QListView item background color

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qlistview

I'm trying to change the background color of the item which currently has the mouse hover.

What I've done so far is: I subclassed QListView and in the ctor:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(entered(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(enteredSlot(QModelIndex)));
```

The job basically needs to be done in the slot `enteredSlot(QModelIndex)` but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you are trying to do a bit easier by [setting a style sheet for your QListView](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlistview). If you haven't worked with style sheets before you may want to back track in the documentation a bit but most common activities related to customizing the appearance of widgets can be done using them. Do not confuse them with QStyles which is a different styling mechanism.